# Is there a way to efficiently get the top n smallest datapoints over the cluster key in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I understand that for Cassandra data is sorted on the cluster key only per partition key.

I am wondering if Cassandra has optimizations on global scans. Lets say that the cluster key is an integer value, if I want to search over all data on a Cassandra cluster to find collections with values `< 3`. The Cassandra query engine will not need to continue looking at collections in a partition after encountering a number `>= 3`. Are there APIs (such as CDK) offered by Cassandra which exercise these optimizations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a native CQL optimisation available for full table scans -- they will always be bad since Cassandra is optimised for OLTP workloads.

There are however optimisations done by the [spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) for analytics (OLAP) workloads with Spark.

OLTP vs OLAP are worlds apart so you have to use the right tool for the job. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Querying by partition key is the best way the query in Cassandra. If you want to use clustering key for querying then you can use "ALLOW FILTERING" option. **But it is recommended not to use "ALLOW FILTERING" in production.**

For scanning complete table and filtering some data, **you can use spark to do your work**. Why bother C* for which it is not designed, better to take help of its friends (spark in this case)